# What is the point of using setContentView with binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

In a project, activity's  `setContentView` is:

```
setContentView<MyActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.activity)
```

What's the distinction with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`T setContentView(activity, layoutId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#setContentView(android.app.Activity,%20int)) is a helper method for [Data Binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) (not to be confused with [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)). Internally it calls the same `setContentView(layoutId)` but also binds views to the binding class and returns it so you can provide data for binding.